# How to change the standard items selection QlistView

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

i have QListView I assigned him my modeland delegate in which I redefined the method `paint(..)`:

```
void PlainDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QRect rect = option.rect;
    QLinearGradient gradient(0,0,rect.width(),rect.height());

    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) 
    {
     gradient.setColorAt(1,Qt::black); //not work
     }

    else if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver&& !isEditorOpen)
    {

       //set gradient
    }
    else
    {
       //set gradient
    }

    painter->fillRect(option.rect, gradient);
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setBrush(gradient);
    painter->drawRect(rect);

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
}
```

it works like that
[image]
As you can see, the elements are overlap by a standard blue window.
How to remove this window?

Comment: You have pointed out how you do not want to obtain but you have not explained or shown the most important thing: what you want to obtain

Comment: @eyllanesc see changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via CSS.

Look at this (in file css or `QWidget::setStyle(QStyle *style)`):

```
QListView::item:selected
{
     border: 1.2px;
     border-color: #273e51;
     border-style: outset;
     ...etc
}

QListView::item:selected:!active
{

}

QListView::item:selected:active
{

}

QListView::item:hover
{

}
```

look at this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html